# Aggregation of array data over a given dimension

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

Forgive the n00b-ish question but I am new to data structures. I had been recently asked to aggregate a given array over another array and produce a tree based result.

Can someone give me some pointers on how to attain this output?

INPUT

```
var T = [
  ['COUNTRY', 'GENDER', 'MARITAL STATUS', 'SALES'],
  ['India', 'Female', 'Single', 2400],
  ['India', 'Male', 'Single', 5200],
  ['India', 'Female', 'Married', 4300],
  ['India', 'Male', 'Married', 3200],
  ['England', 'Female', 'Single', 1600],
  ['England', 'Female', 'Married', 2000],
  ['England', 'Male', 'Single', 4800],
  ['England', 'Male', 'Married', 6400],
];

var A = ['GENDER', 'MARITAL STATUS', 'COUNTRY'];
```

OUTPUT: Use 2*spaces for each leaf node.

```
TOTAL 29900
  Female <Female Total>
    Single <Single Female Total>
      India <Single Female Total India>
      England <Single Female Total England>
    Married <Married Female Total>
      India <Married Female Total India>
      England <Married Female Total England>
  Male <Male Total>
    Single <Single Male Total>
      India <Single Male Total India>
      England <Single Male Total England>
    Married <Married Male Total>
      India <Married Male Total India>
      England <Married Male Total England>
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: updated the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result can be represented by a nested object, each inner object is a sub tree with its total:

```
{
  total: 29900,
  Female: {
    total: 10300,
    Single: {
      total: 4000,
      India: {
        total: 2400
      },
      ...
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Just loop through all then entries, and add values to corresponding sub tree nodes.

For the output, you can use `JSON.stringify` and strip unnecessary text from it.

Warning: spoilers below

```js
const T = [
  ['COUNTRY', 'GENDER', 'MARITAL STATUS', 'SALES'],
  ['India', 'Female', 'Single', 2400],
  ['India', 'Male', 'Single', 5200],
  ['India', 'Female', 'Married', 4300],
  ['India', 'Male', 'Single', 3200],
  ['England', 'Female', 'Single', 1600],
  ['England', 'Female', 'Married', 2000],
  ['England', 'Male', 'Single', 4800],
  ['England', 'Male', 'Married', 6400],
]
const A = ['GENDER', 'MARITAL STATUS', 'COUNTRY']

function aggregate(T, A) {
  const [fields, ...data] = T
  const columns = A.map(name => fields.findIndex(it => name === it))
  const count = fields.length - 1
  const result = { total: 0 }
  data.forEach(values => {
    result.total += values[count]
    //Go through the tree path, reduce is used here
    //to avoid creating extra tracking variable for current position
    columns.reduce((ref, index) => {
      const key = values[index]
      const next = ref[key] || (ref[key] = { total: 0 })
      next.total += values[count]
      return next
    }, result)
  })
  return result
}
function pack(data) {
  return Object.keys(data).reduce((result, key) => {
    if (key !== 'total') {
      const name = key + " " + data[key].total
      result[name] = pack(data[key])
    }
    return result
  }, {})
}
function format(result) {
  return JSON.stringify(pack(result), null, 2)
  .replace(/[^A-z0-9\n\s]/g, '')
  .replace(/\n?\s*\n/g, '\n')
}
function output(it) {
  const result = "TOTAL " + it.total + format(it)
  console.log(result)
}
output(aggregate(T, A))
```

Answer (score 2):

A common approach for working with tree structures is to represent them as nested objects, as demonstrated by [DarkKnight's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41196906/6738706), then create a string representation from this data structure.

In the case presented by the OP, an alternative approach is to first sort the data, then create the string representation of the tree directly from the sorted data without needing any intermediate data structure of nested objects.

Given the array of columns to aggregate by,

```
['GENDER', 'MARITAL STATUS', 'COUNTRY']
```

we can sort the data by these columns:

```
GENDER   STATUS   COUNTRY   SALES
Female   Single   India     2400
Female   Single   England   1600
Female   Married  India     4300
Female   Married  England   2000
Male     Single   India     5200
Male     Single   England   4800
Male     Married  India     3200
Male     Married  England   6400
```

Looping backwards from the last row, while aggregating, we can build the string representation of the tree bottom up. The last row differs from the previous at level 3 (COUNTRY), which gives the following output:

```
      England 6400
```

The row before differs on both level 3 (COUNTRY) and 2 (MARITAL STATUS), prepended to the current output:

```
    Married 9600
      India 3200
      England 6400
```

After the row before that:

```
      England 4800
    Married 9600
      India 3200
      England 6400
```

Then, the 5th row differs from the one before on all 3 levels:

```
  Male 19600
    Single 10000
      India 5200
      England 4800
    Married 9600
      India 3200
      England 6400
```

And so on, until the whole tree is represented:

```
Total 29900
  Female 10300
    Single 4000
      India 2400
      England 1600
    Married 6300
      India 4300
      England 2000
  Male 19600
    Single 10000
      India 5200
      England 4800
    Married 9600
      India 3200
      England 6400
```

Below is working code (ES3 compliant), demonstrating the approach.

```js
var T = [
  ['COUNTRY', 'GENDER', 'MARITAL STATUS', 'SALES'],
  ['India', 'Female', 'Single', 2400],
  ['India', 'Male', 'Single', 5200],
  ['India', 'Female', 'Married', 4300],
  ['India', 'Male', 'Married', 3200],
  ['England', 'Female', 'Single', 1600],
  ['England', 'Female', 'Married', 2000],
  ['England', 'Male', 'Single', 4800],
  ['England', 'Male', 'Married', 6400],
];

var A = ['GENDER', 'MARITAL STATUS', 'COUNTRY'];
var valueField = 'SALES';

// sortBy GENDER ascending
// MARITAL STATUS descending
// COUNTRY descending
var sortDirection = [1, -1, -1];

function find(arr, val){
  for(var i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] === val) return i;
  }
  return -1;
}

function buildTreeString(
    data, aggregateBy, sortDirection, valueField
  ) {
  var i, record,
    value, level,
    groupBy = [],
    result = [],
    sums = [],
    total = 0;
  // get column index of valueField
  valueField = find(data[0], valueField);
  // get column indexes to groupBy
  for(var i = 0; i < aggregateBy.length; i++) {
    groupBy[i] = find(data[0], aggregateBy[i]);
  }
  // sort data
  data = data.slice(1)
    .sort(function(a, b) {
      var i, compare = 0, column;
      for(i = 0; i < groupBy.length && !compare; i++) {
        column = groupBy[i];
        compare = a[column] < b[column] ?
          sortDirection[i] : 
          (a[column] > b[column] ? 
            -sortDirection[i] : 0);
      }
      return compare;
    });
  // loop over data rows, output tree nodes
  for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    record = data[i];
    value = record[valueField];
    total += value;
    //loop over columns, starting from deepest level
    for(level = groupBy.length - 1; level > -1; level--) {
      sums[level] = (sums[level] || 0) + value;
      if(i == data.length - 1 || 
         record[groupBy[level]] != data[i + 1][groupBy[level]]) {
        //output tree node
        result.push(
          Array(level + 2).join('  ') + 
          record[groupBy[level]] + ' ' + 
          sums[level]);
        //reset level aggregation
        sums[level] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  result.push('Total ' + total);
  result.reverse();
  return result.join('\n');
}

console.log(
  buildTreeString(T, A, sortDirection, valueField)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Tree is a good option to implement this question. You can also do the aggregation in one-time pass. The basic idea is

1. sort the data by the given columns.
2. loop the array, check the given column's value

   2.1 aggregate the group count if column's value is as same as previous line

   2.2 output group name and count if column's value is different with previous line

Here is a example which I guided a CS student for his assignment, which is pretty similar to yours.

The method sumaryStage3 at [Here](https://gist.github.com/passos/738ce9c025c7cfd88e39da50835ea9da) implement the logic of steps 2.

Pls ignore the code style and quality. It's not my code.